# Interrogative for only two choices?

Tags: words, questions

This is a quick one. I read in the dictionary that どれ is only supposed to be used when there are three or more choices. What word should I use if I have only two choices?

Comment: try どちら. Also see http://people.uncw.edu/kanoy/practices/interrogatives.html

Comment: 日常会話なら「どっち？」でいいよね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どちら (very seldomly written as 何方), or the colloquial どっち. Both can also mean "where (to)"